# Expand one row at a time in UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, swift2

I am working on expanding row when tapped on table view row. My logic is simple I am adding an extra row when tapped on visible row(i.e Expanding) and I delete it i.e remove/collapse the added row when tapped on expanded visible row. Now I have 4 custom cells with separate XIB's i.e A, B, C, D and all of them are contained in one Class. Now the issue goes something like this consider I expand cell A at row 0 and next row is also of type A then the instance goes to the second open cell and when I tap on first open cell it crashes. Now I have 2 solutions first is to show only one cell at a time and collapse all the remaining open cell if any or else second is solve the crash issue that doesn't get the cells instance. I have tried to solve the first issue by creating

`let indexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.view!.tag, section: 0)
self.expansionCell = self.myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell`

But still it crashes.

Second one I tried the below

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    if isExpanded == true
    {
        print("Expanded Row",self.expandedIndex)
       //Function to contract Cell which holds old expanded cell index
       self.contractExpandedCell(tableView: tableView, index: self.expandedIndex)
    }

    //Setting Selected index path
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath

    if myArray[indexPath.row] != nil {
        let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        // If user clicked last cell, do not try to access cell+1 (out of range)
        if(indexPath.row + 1 >= (myArray.count)) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.forwardArrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            }
            self.isExpanded = true

            //Function to expand Cell
            expandCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)

        }
        else {
            // If next cell is not nil, then cell is not expanded
            if(myArray[indexPath.row+1] != nil) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.forwardArrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2))

                }
                self.isExpanded = true
                self.expandCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)

            } else {
                // Close Cell (remove ExpansionCells)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.forwardArrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(180.0 * M_PI))
                }
                self.isExpanded = false
                contractCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)

            }
        }
    }

}
 //Function to expand cell  
 private func expandCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
    // Expand Cell (add ExpansionCells)
    if (myArray[index]?.title) != nil {
        myArray.insert(nil, at: index + 1)
        self.expandedIndex = index + 1
        questionAnswerTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index + 1, section: 0)], with: .top)
    }
}

//Function to contract cell  
private func contractCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
    if (myArray[index]?.title) != nil {
        myArray.remove(at: index + 1)
        questionAnswerTable.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index + 1, section: 0 )], with: .top)
    }

}
```

Even this doesn't work smoothly as when a row is added the row count changes and if I try to expand the next cell it opens the third one.

Any one solution will work.
Please help guys. TIA

Comment: In the first solution that you have tried, are you reloading the cell after contracting?

Answer (score 0):

Add

> var  currentExpandIndexpath : NSIndexpath?

and in `didSelectRowAt`  change

```
expandCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)
```

with

```
if currentExpandIndexpath == nil{  
   currentExpandIndexpath = indexpath  
}  
if currentExpandIndexpath == indexpath{  
   // do nothing  
}else{    
// contract expand cell before expand new cell  
    contractCell(tableView: tableView, index: currentExpandIndexpath.row)  
    self.expandCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)  
// update current expand cell  
    currentExpandIndexpath = indexpath  
}
```

it 's just solution. Not correct code.

Comment: Its deleting my rows. The which should not be. And as the row number changes I mentioned in the question it opens any row according to indexpath.row :(

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple logic. Get an variable to store selected indexpath.

When any cell tapped on DidSelectRowAtIndexPath store selected indeapth to that variable and reload table.

When table reload on height row method check for the indexpath. if indexpath is equal to the indexpath store in variable then that row should have larger size then other.

It is just simple logic

Comment: I have implemented this kind of functionalities so many times. There should be some kind of errors there otherwise this is the simple solution for one row expand collapse functioanlities